# C# - Dynamic Data Unit Tests - Report Separately

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

#### Description

I want my Dynamic Data Unit Tests results to be reported separately, for each run.

Here is my Unit Test:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetNames()
{            
    yield return new object[] { "a" };
    yield return new object[] { "b" };
    yield return new object[] { "c" };
}

[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(GetNames), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void Test123(string str)
{
    Assert.IsNull(str);
}
```

#### Results

Currently, when I run these tests I get the following response:

[image: current_tests]

However, in a different project it reports like so:

[image: tests_i_want]

This is what I want.

#### Question

Is there a project setting that allows this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your version number and operation process.

But if you directly create a Unit Test (.Net Framework project) and put it into your code to run, it will be the effect you want.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetNames()
        {
            yield return new object[] { "a" };
            yield return new object[] { "b" };
            yield return new object[] { "c" };
        }

        [DataTestMethod]
        [DynamicData(nameof(GetNames), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
        public void Test123(string str)
        {
            Assert.IsNull(str);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]